# Likelihood-based CI is better than Wald CI?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, maximum-likelihood, wald-test

The text I'm reading mentions the following:

Let us consider a scalar parameter case. The likelihood-based approximate 95% cI is
$$\left\{\theta,2\log\frac{L(\hat{\theta})}{L(\theta)} \le3.84 \right\}$$

where the 3.84 is derived from the chi-square distribution.  And the Wald interval is

$$\hat{\theta} \pm 1.96se(\hat{\theta})$$

The Wald interval is correct only if:
$$\frac{\hat{\theta}-\theta}{se(\hat{\theta})} \sim N(0,1)$$

in contrast, because of invariance the likelihood based interval is correct as long as there exists a one-to-one transformation $g(\cdot)$:
$$\frac{g(\hat{\theta})-g(\theta)}{se(g(\hat{\theta}))} \sim N(0, 1)$$

It's from this point that I do not understand:

To show this, suppose $L < g(\theta) < U$ is the 95% CI for $g(\theta)$ based on $g(\hat{\theta})$. From normality of $g(\hat{\theta})$ the interval (L,U) is a likelihood interval at 15% cutoff. The invariance of the likelihood ratio implies that the likelihood interval of θ at 15% cutoff is
$$g^{-1}(L) < \theta < g^{-1}(U)$$
Which then has exactly the same 95% confidence level.

---

Q.

1. Why does all of this make the likelihood based CI better than the Wald CI? The text mentions: -"the likelihood-based CI is automatically employing the best possible normalizing transform". However, I cannot recognise this in the text.

Comment: Too many questions pooled.

Comment: The invariance property you are referring to implies that the confidence interval does not depend on the scale chosen for the parameter.  In the logistic regression setting, if one obtained a Wald CI for $p$ it would be different than that obtained from $\mbox{logit}(p)$ after transforming it back to the scale $p$.  This does not occur for LR CI.  Also the applicability of the large sample chi-squared approximation tends to hold for smaller sample sizes of the LR CI than the Wald CI.  Finally, the Wald CI does not respect the parameter space like the LR CI and Score CI, giving useless results

Comment: The OP is interesting as I had not seen this stated in terms of optimal transformation.  But regardless we know that confidence interval coverage in non-normal cases is better with profile likelihood intervals (the type being discussed) than with Wald intervals.

Comment: can you add a reference to the text?